# TeamSpeak in VOX mode on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, arm

I would really like to run a TeamSpeak client in VOX mode on my Pi. My goal is to hook the Pi to a USB sound card and wire that to my two way portable radio that is VOX.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is a team speak client for pi arm. So I guess you can't do this out of the box.

Comment: Mumble to the rescue!